# Mongoose, "the options [port] is not supported"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Anyone know why I keep getting this in the console log, when using mongoose

`the options [port] is not supported`

quick context:

- running `mongod` locally
- running node/express app locally
- "mongoose": "^5.6.11"
- mongodb v4.0.10
- code snippet below:

```
const mongoProfile = require('../config/mongo-profile.json');
let mongooseConnPromise = mongoose.connect(mongoProfile.url, mongoProfile.connectionOptions);
let dbConn = mongoose.connection;
dbConn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

dbConn.on('open', () => {
    RpDataModel.find({$or: queryData},
    (err, docs) => {
      dbConn.close();
      res.append('ETag', `My PerfTest, ${new Date(Date.now())}`);
      res.json(docs);
  });

});
```

*"('../config/mongo-profile.json')"*  conn str and options below

```
{
    "url": "mongodb://localhost",
    "connectionOptions": {
      "useNewUrlParser": true,
      "port": 27017,
      "user": "rpTest",
      "dbName":"rp-db-perf-test",
      "pass":"...",
      "keepAlive": true,
      "keepAliveInitialDelay": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Mongoose specialist but, according to the documentation, `port` is not a valid option:

Mongoose uses Node.js MongoDB Driver. Here is the list of [available connection options](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoClient.html).

According to Mongoose docs, the correct way to connect is using [MongoDB Standard Connection String Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format), that is:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[database][?options]]
```

You can see some examples in Mongoose's [Connections](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) documentation.

From what I understand, you can change your `mongo-profile.json` to:

```
{
    "url": "mongodb://localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "user": "rpTest",
    "dbName":"rp-db-perf-test",
    "pass":"...",
    "connectionOptions": {
      "useNewUrlParser": true,
      "keepAlive": true,
      "keepAliveInitialDelay": 0
    }
}
```

And your connection code to:

```
const mongoProfile = require('../config/mongo-profile.json');
var url = mongoProfile.url;
var port = mongoProfile.port;
var dbName = mongoProfile.dbName;
var user = mongoProfile.user;
var pass = mongoProfile.pass;

let mongooseConnPromise = mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://' + user + ':' + pass + '@' + url + ':' + port + '/' + dbName, 
    mongoProfile.connectionOptions
);
let dbConn = mongoose.connection;
dbConn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, even if you are using the oldest version of mongoose out there (3.8), you cannot specify a port like that. The only way according to the docs is passing it in the connection string like so:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://host:port');
```

But since you are using localhost with the default port, you don't even need the port to be specified there:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://host');
```

So just remove the parameter from your configuration file and you are good to go.